# Storing multiple tables by type vs one table

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-design

I want to store a lot of rows in a table, but I will often want to select only some of them, depending of their type. So I could just add a column `type` to each row, but then, if I want to select only the rows of one type, I'll have to make a query like `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE type = 1` for example. But does it mean that the DBMS will have to fetch all the table, even if only a few rows have the type that I want?

Is it better to have a table per type, so I could just `SELECT * FROM MyTableType1`, without having to use a `WHERE`?

Comment: One entity - one table. A table per type - forget this forever. You must index it (and may partition it) by type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as all the data have (roughly) the same attributes, and the only difference is the `type`, storing them in a single table is fine.

To make your query fast, create an index on `type`. Then two things can happen:

- there are few enough rows of that `type` that you get an index scan (or bitmap index scan in PostgreSQL)
- the `type` occurs often enough that PostgreSQL opts for a sequential scan

In both cases you won't be much slower than with many small tables.

The final decision might depend on the number of tables (having 10000 tables in a database is not much fun) and the type of query you have:

- The following can be a static query with parameters:

  ```
  SELECT ... FROM mytable WHERE type = 'type1';
  ```

  while the following requires you to compose an SQL statement for every query:

  ```
  SELECT ... FROM mytable_type1;
  ```
- If you want to query several types at once, it is nicer to write

  ```
  SELECT ... FROM mytable WHERE type IN ('type1', 'type2', 'type3');
  ```

  than having to write

  ```
  SELECT ... FROM mytable_type1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ... FROM mytable_type2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ... FROM mytable_type3;
  ```